# Visually coding rpg dialog trees

Tags: software-engineering, rpg

I am currently using XML to create my dialog trees in my rpg, but doing this by hand for hundreds of different discussions can get very tedious very fast. I was wondering if there is any way I can implement a flow chart/udk kismet like system of visually coding these diolog trees. I still want the end result to be the XML because I already wrote the parsing and other logic around the XML.

EDIT: to give an idea of what I am looking for, [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?220908-Dialogue-Editor-create-dialogue-trees-for-your-game) is an example. This was shown to me when I asked this on reddit and it is basically what I am looking for but it is limiting . Really what I am looking for is any dialog software that is already in use for games or software that is graph/flowchart like and can be modified to suit my needs.

Comment: I suppose using an existing XML editor or UML diagram creator, then transforming the result (via XSLT or something less design-patterny) is not an option?

Comment: The answer is "yes."  Do you have a specific question about how to implement such an editor?  Are you confused about what UI toolkits have decent support for general-purpose graph-like canvas scenes?  Because the answer to that is "most UI toolkits can do that, and building your own is not particularly difficult."  Please expand the question with more details about what you need help doing specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found these

- [Chat Mapper](http://www.chat-mapper.com/)
- [Dialog Designer](http://www.bigbluecup.com/yabb/index.php?topic=39568.0)

You could also use [XML Notepad](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7973), which makes editing XML a little more bearable. You could also use [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)/[Freeplane](http://freeplane.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and other mindmap software that would generate XML. You just need to set up some semantics for how to structure data in each node and write your parser accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [Workflowy](https://workflowy.com/) could work, with each indentation representing a branch point.

Comment: -1 This isn't what the asker is after. They want a way to write out dialog trees which would be automatically converted into XML format, probably something that has nice visualisation as a plus - not a way to draft them.